# How to set all factors in a plot to be the same colour regardless of how many there are in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, data-visualization

I have a plot with a geom_area() section that shows whether an event is active or not at a certain step in a simulation (thanks to this community for helping me with that too!).

It works well when I am only showing one run of the simulation, however I need to be able to show more than one run at a time, to see any differences between the timing of this event in different runs.

I set the fill of geom_area() to correspond to the run number, and the position to position_dodge(0) to be able to overlap the areas so that the denser the colour, the more runs had an event active at that point. The only problem is that I am not interested in differentiating the runs, so I would like them to have all the same colour. I managed to do it with a bit of a hack, by simply making a palette that had grey 10 times, however this is not something I can do manually since I will have graphs with 100s of runs soon.

How can I make all factors the same colour regardless of how many there are? Or if there is a better solution to show a plot like the one below, what is it?

Including the plot I managed so far (which is exactly what I need, only scalable) and the code I used to make it:

[image]

```r
ggplot(df,aes(x = step, y = count)) +
  geom_area(data = event, aes(x = step, y = pop_size * event, fill = as.factor(run_num)),
            inherit.aes = FALSE, position = position_dodge(0), alpha = 0.2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(aes(color = breed), alpha = 0.7, size = 1) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
  # horrible hack incoming
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightgrey","lightgrey","lightgrey","lightgrey","lightgrey",
                               "lightgrey","lightgrey","lightgrey","lightgrey","lightgrey")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, pop_size))
```

Comment: scale_fill_manual(values = rep("lightgrey", n_simulations)) where n_simulations is the number of lines you're drawing.

Comment: Omg yes! Can't believe I hadn't thought of that... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this thanks to the comment by d-a-wells above, who suggested using `scale_fill_manual(values = rep("lightgrey", n_simulations))` to ensure the palette covers however many factors I have. Can't believe I didn't think of it!